# Account gets locked every time while trying to access via the V1APIConnector

Tags: java, sdk, versionone

I am trying to access the VersionOne data using the V1APIConnector. I can verify that I am using the correct data and meta URLs. I also have the correct domain/username and password.
But everytime I execute the below code, I get an Authentication error saying username/password is invalid and my account gets locked. 
Once I unlocked my account, I tried again and the account was locked again. I am the V1 Administrator so I have the permissions.

Our VersionOne instance uses Windows Integrated Auththentication. Also my username is in the format -mydomain/myusername

Is there any different way to pass the credentials? Since my account is getting locked, it must mean at least the domain and the username are being passed correctly. Any Ideas?

```
V1APIConnector dataConnector = new V1APIConnector( _dataUrl, _username, _password);
V1APIConnector metaConnector = new V1APIConnector( _metaUrl );
IMetaModel metaModel = new MetaModel(metaConnector);
IServices services = new Services(metaModel, dataConnector);
System.out.println("Creating query");
IAssetType defectType = metaModel.getAssetType("Defect");
Query query = new Query(defectType);
IAttributeDefinition nameAttribute = defectType.getAttributeDefinition("Name");
query.getSelection().add(nameAttribute);
query.getPaging().setPageSize(3);
query.getPaging().setStart(0);
System.out.println("Retrieve from query");
QueryResult result = services.retrieve(query);
```

Comment: Bump..Any ideas why account gets locked? As the user account gets locked, it ,must means the password is not getting through correctly. Would a UTF-8 encoded password work?

Answer (score 0):

The Java.SDK ignores the username and password parameters of the V1APIConnector constructor when attempting to connect to a Windows Integrated instance, and instead uses the domain credentials that it is running under. If you are logged into your machine as "MyDomain\MyUsername" then that is the credentials that it will use. It does not support supplying the credentials of another account.

Note that there must also exist a VersionOne member account with the username set to "MyDomain\MyUsername" to successfully authenticate.

VersionOne locks accounts only when your license has expired, and if that happens, only the system administrator (Member:20) will remain active. In addition, administrators can deactivate accounts manually.